# Bookstore software in java: basic classes- need help for APCS

Tags: java, arraylist, constructor, initialization

I am having a problem with the program I am trying to make. When I implement an arraylist, it is giving me different errors. I am very confused right now on how to initialize my ArrayList of type book.

Here is the Book class:

```
public class Book {

    private double myPrice;
    private String myTitle;
    private String bookAuthor;
    private String isbn;
    private int myCopies;   

    public Book(double price, int copies, String bookTitle, String Author, String isbnNumber) {
        myPrice = price;
        myCopies = copies;
        myTitle = bookTitle;
        bookAuthor = Author;
        isbn = isbnNumber;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return myPrice;
    }

    public String getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return myTitle;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return bookAuthor;
    }

    public int copiesLeft(){
        return myCopies;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Title: " + getTitle() + "\nAuthor: " + getAuthor()
               + "\nNumber of Available Books: " + copiesLeft() 
               + "\nPrice: $" + getPrice(); 
    }

}
```

And here is the Inventory Class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Inventory extends Book {
    private ArrayList<Book> allBooks = new ArrayList<Book>;
    private String customerName;

    public Inventory() {
        super();
    }

    //@param double price, int copies, String bookTitle, String Author, String isbnNumber
    public void addBooks() {
        allBooks.add(new Book(4.99, 6, "A Tale of Two Cities", "Charles Dickens", "9781783220731"));
    }

    public boolean isAvailable() {
        for(Book myBook : allBooks) {
            if(myBook.copiesLeft() == 0)
                return false;
            else
                return true;    
        }
    }

    public Book getBookByTitle(String titleSearch) {
        for (Book myBook : allBooks) {
            if (titleSearch.equals(myBook.getTitle()));
                return myBook;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What errors? You're going to have to give more information if you want help.

Comment: Exactly what error(s)?  Corresponding to which lines?  SUGGESTION: instead of "myPrice", name the variable `price`, and initialize with `this.price = price;`

Comment: Why have you made `Inventory` a sub-class of `Book`?

Comment: Also, you realize constructors are a type of method, right? (in other words, you're missing `()` on the `ArrayList` constructor)

Comment: @user3580294 Is correct, this `private ArrayList<Book> allBooks = new ArrayList<Book>(); // <--- Added paren`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which errors you got, and therefore it's a bit hard to help you. But here are some of the errors in your code. They're marked with //<----

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Inventory extends Book {
    private ArrayList<Book> allBooks = new ArrayList<Book>; //<---- Should be new ArrayList<Book>(); that is, with parentheses.
    private String customerName;

    public Inventory() {
        super(); //<---- I'm rusty on inheritance, but this line** might fuck up some stuff
    }

    //@param double price, int copies, String bookTitle, String Author, String isbnNumber
    public void addBooks() {
        allBooks.add(new Book(4.99, 6, "A Tale of Two Cities", "Charles Dickens", "9781783220731"));
    }

    public boolean isAvailable() {
        for(Book myBook : allBooks) {
            if(myBook.copiesLeft() == 0)
                return false;
            else
                return true;    
        }
            //<---- You need a second return statement, in case the for-loop and if statement is never accessed. The method always needs to return something when you've told it to.
    }

    public Book getBookByTitle(String titleSearch) {
        for (Book myBook : allBooks) {
            if (titleSearch.equals(myBook.getTitle())); //<---- Semicolon
                return myBook;
        }
            //<---- You need a second return statement, in case the for-loop and if statement is never accessed. The method always needs to return something when you've told it to.
    }
}
```

It would be easier to help if you could post the main method and the specific errors you get.

Also, as pointed out by Elliott; I'm not sure why you've extended class Inventory with Book.

** I might be in the wrong here; When calling super(), which in this case is constructor in Books(?), there might spawn errors since you're lacking parameters. This method call should probably not be in this class, since Inventory probably shouldn't extend Book.